# Custom relation created in Cameo - date attribute not showing up in table?

Tags: model, sysml, magic-draw, requirements-management, model-based-testing

I am creating a custom relationship based on an existing relationship type within Cameo systems modeler. I created a few custom attributes for this relation, one of which is "date of submission". I set the "Type" to "date".

But when I create a generic table of all the custom relation instances, and include the custom column for "date of submission", it doesn't give me a pop-up to select the date. It instead gives me the standard pop-up for selecting an element from the containment tree. Is there something I could've missed in my process?

For reference I am trying to follow the process set forth by the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyLTf9Xbr4U&t=162s&ab_channel=MBSEExecution

(see around the 4:53 time stamp) - this date pop-up doesn't show up for me.